# Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64 filterable and/or sortable attributes . How to Increase this Limit for 500 Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, indexer, flat-catalog

I created 300 filterable and Sort able Attribute in Magento.
I also Enabled Flat category option in Catlog.
But When I Indexed  The New Added Product It says.
**The Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64 filterable and/or sortable attributes. Currently there are 329 of them. Please reduce the number of filterable/sortable attributes in order to use this module** 
when I disable Flat Category of Product it working fine.
How can Solved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In `config.xml` of the `Mage_Catalog` module there is this: `<max_index_count>64</max_index_count>`. You can try to increase this limit, but I don't know the implications.
You can do that by adding this in the config.xml from any one of your modules inside the `<global>` tag.

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <flat>
            <max_index_count>64</max_index_count>
        </flat>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

Comment: I got this error  Cannot initialize the indexer process.  when indexing product

Comment: @DeepakRai try stopping MySQL deleting the files in your /var/locks , start MySQL and reindex.